# css: show div when another div is hover

Tags: jquery, css

I've got 2 divs. Div A and Div B. If Div A is hovered, then I need show Div B. Can this be achieved with pure css only? Or if I do it in query, how do i go about with this base on the assumption that we cannot use id for these 2 divs.

Thanks

Comment: Show us some HTML so we can see how to distinguish these two DIVs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assuming the two `div`s are contained in a `div`:

http://jsfiddle.net/4p8CM/1/

```
#container > div {
    display: none
}
#container > div:first-child {
    display: block
}
#container > div:hover + div {
    display: block
}

<div id="container">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
</div>
```

The `:first-child` stuff is to work around this limitation that you set:

> base on the assumption that we cannot
>   use id for these 2 divs

---

If you want the second `div` to stay visible when you hover over it, try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4p8CM/3/

```
#container > div {
    display: none
}
#container > div:first-child {
    display: block
}
#container:hover > div {
    display: block
}
```

Comment: +1 for a working solution.  Also, you could do the same thing with classes, of course.

Answer (score 6):

Please note that I've used element `id`s in these examples to identify which, specific, elements are used. In place of `id`s you could use almost any other CSS-selector, the important thing is the relationships *between* the selected elements; in the first example I've used the [adjacent-sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors), and in the latter the [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

If you post your mark-up, and notify me with a comment, I'll try and revise the selectors to match what you're working with. Otherwise this is just a generic best-guess. And they're not always that useful...

That said, the answers appear below:

If you've got super-simple mark-up then this *can* be accomplished via CSS:

```
#divB {
    display: none;
}

#divA:hover + #divB {
    display:  block;
}

<div id="divA">
    Some content in 'divA'
</div>
<div id="divB">
    Some content in 'divB'
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r46FB/). Or:

```
#divB {
    display: none;
}

#divA:hover #divB {
    display:  block;
}

<div id="divA">
    Some content in 'divA'
    <div id="divB">
        Some content in 'divB'
    </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r46FB/1/).

Comment: Your first answer was better because it didn't use IDs. It's been **stated explicitly** you **can't use IDs**.

Comment: Well, yeah; unfortunately without mark-up it's impossible to offer a solution using anything else. Albeit classes would work just as easily...

Comment: I realize that the question was "without using IDs", but this question showed up as #1 in google and this solution worked for me (using classes).  So +1 and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you add a container to div A and div B you can do it very easy in this way:

```
<style>
/* Only for testing */
.a, .b {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
/* Hide the B div */
.b {
    display:none;
}
/* Show the B div when hover on A (the container include only A when B is not displayed */
.container:hover .b {
    display: block;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/royshoa/bzhz8pou/