# css rule to display div when hover another div depending from variable

Tags: css, html, rules

hello i found an interesting way to make a div visible while hovering another div.
i´ve been following this example from the accepted answer of this question:

[question from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766141/css-show-div-when-another-div-is-hover) and did it like that:

[example code](http://jsfiddle.net/4p8CM/3/)

now i run into problems while creating that css rules. the problem is that i have a structure like that:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="list">
            <span class="up">some text</span>
            <ul class="nav">some content</ul>
                    <div class="flag">
                         <div id="<?php echo $variable;?>"></div>**---->here comes the variable that is neccessary for the css rule**
                         <div id="drop_down">the div that will displayed when hover flag</div>              
                    </div><!--flag -->
        </div><!--list -->
    </div><!--content -->
</div><!--Footer -->
```

so the structure for the css rule is like:

```
.footer #content #list .flag > #$variable+#drop_down {
    display: none;
}
.footer #content #list .flag > #$variable+#drop_down:first-child {
    display: block;
}

.footer #content #list .flag:hover > #$variable+#drop_down {
    display: block;
}
```

so when `$variable` will be `a` for example the html would be:

```
<div class="flag">
    <div id="a"></div>
    div id="drop_down">some content</div>               
</div><!--flag -->
```

and the css rule:

```
.footer #content #list .flag > #a+#drop_down...
.footer #content #list .flag > #a+#drop_down:first-child...
.footer #content #list .flag:hover > #a+#drop_down...
```

but what in case of `$variable` is not equal `a` for example `b`?

i tried different ways like:

```
.footer #content #list .flag > #a,#b+#drop_down...
.footer #content #list .flag > #a,#b+#drop_down:first-child...
.footer #content #list .flag:hover > #a,#b+#drop_down...
```

or

```
.footer #content #list .flag > #a+#b+#drop_down...
.footer #content #list .flag > #a+#b+#drop_down:first-child...
.footer #content #list .flag:hover > #a+#b+#drop_down...
```

or

```
.footer #content #list .flag > #a+#drop_down,
.footer #content #list .flag > #b+#drop_down,
...
.footer #content #list .flag > #a+#drop_down:first-child,
.footer #content #list .flag > #b+#drop_down:first-child,
...
.footer #content #list .flag:hover > #a+#drop_down,
.footer #content #list .flag:hover > #b+#drop_down...
```

but no one of these worked.

so if there is someone who could tell me on how to fetch this i really would appreciate.

thanks alot.

Comment: I hope I had understand right your issue. I don't have an answers to make working fine your CSS .. But only a suggestion: have you thinked to use a javascript framework? Doing what you need with jQuery, for example, should be really easy and fast..

Comment: hello, yes i did. i have already done it before this way. but now i would like to learn something from css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the `<div>` with the variable `class` is always the first `child` of `.flag` you could use the pseudeo-element selector [:first-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp).

```
.footer #content #list .flag > div:first-child+#drop_down
```

Like you did for the `#drop_down` div.