# Only target one div .on() hover, not all - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using the code to animate opacity to 1 on mouseenter of an image and back to 0 again on mouseleave. Instead of it displaying one image, it displays all on hover.

I've tried using `(this)` instead of `(.project-hover img)` so it only affects that particular div but I need to target `(.project-hover img)` instead of `.span4` upon which the function is initiated from.

How would I go about achieving this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".span4").on("mouseenter", function() {
        $('.project-hover img').stop();//halts previous animation if it's running
        $('.project-hover img').animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        $('.project-hover img').stop();
        $('.project-hover img').animate({
            opacity: 0
        });
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="span4">
    <div class="wrap-title">
        <div class="position">
            <div class="title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></div>
            <div class="tags"><?php echo $cats; ?> </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="project-hover"><img src="<?php echo catch_that_image(); ?>">    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find()` see documentation...  http://api.jquery.com/find/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".span4").on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(this).find('.project-hover img').stop();//halts previous animation if it's running
        $(this).find('.project-hover img').animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).find('.project-hover img').stop();
        $(this).find('.project-hover img').animate({
           opacity: 0
        });
    });
});
```

---

**Update:**

You should also be chaining your methods for efficiency, and you probally want to be passing in `true, true` to your [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method. (to prevent queue iusses)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".span4").on("mouseenter", function() {
            $(this).find('.project-hover img').stop(true, true).animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
        }).on("mouseleave", function() {
            $(this).find('.project-hover img').stop(true, true).animate({
               opacity: 0
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".span4").on("mouseenter", function() {
        $('.project-hover img', $(this)).stop();//halts previous animation if it's running
        $('.project-hover img', $(this)).animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        $('.project-hover img', $(this)).stop();
        $('.project-hover img', $(this)).animate({
           opacity: 0
        });
    });
```

Comment: using `.find()` is actually faster than this approach

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the current `.span4` element the user is hovering over, so all you have to do is find the target element inside of it:

```
$(this).find('.project-hover img').animate(...);
```

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated events `this` is an element matching `selector`. (Note that this may not be equal to `event.target` if the event has bubbled from a descendant element.) To create a jQuery object from the element so that it can be used with jQuery methods, use `$(this)`.

List of DOM traversal methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS solution I've found here incase anyone wanted this simpler alternative for future reference:

[css: show div when another div is hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766141/css-show-div-when-another-div-is-hover)

Comment: Okay but that was not the question, and if u wanted it to be animated like your question you will need to use CSS3 which doesnt have legacy support.