# Hover CSS menu does not work on iOS

Tags: ios, css, hover

This is the code I have for a menu on my publishing company's site. For some reason the drop down menu (in the publishing tab) only works on the FAQ page, but not on any other page. If someone could help me find a workaround, that would be great. Everything works great on my android phone, so I'm not sure what the problem is. (might just need a mobile site, but I'd like to get this to work)

```
<div class="publishingmenu"><ul>
    <li id="pm1" onclick="return true">
        <a class="plevel1" href="#">Submit a Manuscript</a>
        <ul class="submenu" id="submitamanuscript">
        <li><a href="submissionguidelines.php">Submission Guidelines</a></li>
        <li id="onlinesubmissionform"><a href="onlinesubmissionform.php">Online Submission Form</a></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li id="pm2" onclick="return true">
        <a class="plevel1" href="#">Publishing Packages</a>
        <ul class="submenu" id="publishingpackages">
        <li class="inactive">Black & White</li>
        <li><a href="softcoverpackages.php"><span class="tabbed">Softcover</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="hardcoverpackages.php"><span class="tabbed">Hardcover</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="combopackages.php"><span class="tabbed">Combination</span></a></li>
        <li class="inactive">Color</li>
        <li><a href="colorsoftcoverpackages.php"><span class="tabbed">Softcover</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="colorhardcoverpackages.php"><span class="tabbed">Hardcover</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="colorcombo.php"><span class="tabbed">Combination</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="color.php"><span class="tabbed">Color Options</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="ebookpackage.php">Ebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="additionalservices.php">Additional Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="marketing.php">Marketing</a></li><em></em>
        <li><a href="self-publishing.php">Self-Publishing</a></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li id="pm3" onclick="return true"><a class="plevel1" href="#">Information</a>
        <ul class="submenu" id="information">
        <li><a href="comparisonchart.php">Comparison Chart</a></li>
        <li><a href="calcpage.php">Production Calculator</a></li>
        <li><a href="layouttemplates.php">Layout Templates</a></li>
        <li><a href="covertemplates.php">Cover Templates</a></li>
        <li><a href="testimonials.php">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="informationpackets.php">Information Packets</a></li>
        <li><a href="podglossary.php">POD Glossary</a></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li id="pm4"><a class="plevel1" href="faqs.php">FAQS</a></li>
    <li id="pm5"><a class="plevel1" href="sample.php">Printed Sample</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS

```
         #publishbookguy{height:160px; width:139px; position:absolute; z-index:9; right:20px; top:25px;}
    .publishingmenu ul{list-style:none; margin:-15px 0 0 10px; }
    .publishingmenu li{display:inline;}
        .publishingmenu a.plevel1{width:120px; height:50px; display:inline-block;  text-indent:-9999px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright:10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:10px; border-bottom-left-radius:10px; background-color:#f7a553; position:relative; z-index:10;}
        #pm1 a.plevel1{background-image:url(images/publishingmenu.png); background-position: 0 0;}
        #pm1 a.plevel1:hover{background-position: 0 -50px;}
        #pm2 a.plevel1{background-image:url(images/publishingmenu.png); background-position:-120px 0;}
        #pm2 a.plevel1:hover{background-position: -120px -50px;}
        #pm3 a.plevel1{background-image:url(images/publishingmenu.png); background-position:-240px 0;}
        #pm3 a.plevel1:hover{background-position: -240px -50px;}
        #pm4 a.plevel1{background-image:url(images/publishingmenu.png); background-position:-360px 0;}
        #pm4 a.plevel1:hover{background-position: -360px -50px;}
        #pm4 a.plevel1:active{background-position: -360px -100px;}
        #pm5 a.plevel1{background-image:url(images/publishingmenu.png); background-position:-480px 0;}
        #pm5 a.plevel1:hover{background-position: -480px -50px;}
        #pm5 a.plevel1:active{background-position: -480px -100px;}  
            /*Submenu*/
            .publishingmenu .submenu a{display:block; height:30px; width:200px; background:#f7a553;
            text-indent:20px; line-height:30px; font-family: 'Caudex', arial, serif; color:#000000;
            -moz-border-radius:5px; border-radius:5px; background-image:url(images/menuborders.png); font-size:14px; z-index:300;}
                .publishingmenu .submenu a:link{text-decoration: none; color:#000000; background-position: 0 0;}
                .publishingmenu .submenu a:visted{text-decoration: none; color:#000000; background-position: 0 0;}
                .publishingmenu .submenu a:hover{text-decoration: none; color:#00588e; background-position: 0 -30px; font-weight:bold;}
                .publishingmenu .submenu a:active{text-decoration: none; color:#0c94e0; ; background-position: 0 -60px;}
            .publishingmenu ul.submenu{visibility:hidden; opacity:0; -webkit-transition: all .3s linear; position:absolute; z-index:300; margin-top:0px; padding-top:2px;}
                ul#submitamanuscript{left:0px;} ul#submitamanuscript a{text-indent:10px;}
                ul#publishingpackages{ left:85px;}
                ul#information{left:210px;}
            .publishingmenu li:hover ul, li.over ul, .publishingmenu li:active ul {visibility:visible; opacity:1;}
            li.inactive{font-weight:bold; display:block; height:30px; width:200px; background:#f7a553; line-height:30px; background-image:url(images/menuborders.png); background-position: 0 0; text-indent:20px; font-family: 'Caudex', arial, serif; color:#000000; }
            .tabbed{position:relative; left:20px;}
```

Comment: I had a very similar difficulty that I outlined a response to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16445223/2183554).

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the culprit:

```
<li id="pm1" onclick="return true">
```

Because you are specifying an `onclick` behaviour, the iOS browser thinks it is important, and elects to execute it instead of handling the CSS hover behaviour. Removing the `onclick` will likely solve the issue on iOS (not sure why you put it there anyway).

Comment: I put it there, because I was google-ing solutions and that was supposed to be one of them. I can go ahead and remove it, because it did nothing. But the FAQ page still works with that in also, so I'm confused.